# How capture Logs & Crash reporting in Android / iOS mobile SDK product?

Tags: android, logging, sdk, crash-reports

We are developing an Android / iOS mobile SDK which will be integrated by 3rd party applications (of our customers).

So I'm trying to finalise on what is the best & standard way to detect issues / crashes & logging for debugging.

Please share your suggestions on what is the best way to go about here, also if any reads available on this.

Since this is our product is an SDK which will be integrated with other apps, I believe we can't use 3rd party libraries like fabric for logs/crash reporting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Crashlytics. It supports both Android and IOS. It provides the exact line of code where the app is causing to crash. Other than that you have some more benefits such as

- Crashlytics gives you powerful crash reporting
- with one additional click, you can enable real-time analytics that help you understand what’s happening in your app
- Fabric’s analytics engine provides insights into your core goals, such as growth, retention, and engagement

Following URL will help to set up on your project
[setup crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install)

Comment: I can use crash analytics, if mine was a mobile app instead my product is an SDK. So multiple concerns arise here :

1. Privacy can be an issues here, as could be injecting a 3rd party sdk into my customer's app here. 

2. There could be dependency issues, if the App is already using the same crash/logging tool.

Comment: @SreejithK did you find an answer, finally? What did you implement?

Answer (score 0):

For Android you can implement `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` as in this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-global-exception-handler)

you'll get all the crashes which you can send to your own server using Retrofit or other Networking libraries. I believe similarly **NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler**  is also available for IOS. Search about **NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler** this i'm not well versed with IOS